# How to query a Lotus view and have the result formatted as json?

Tags: json, lotus-domino

I have a view called 'walking' which I want to query:

```
http://site/activity.nsf/walking?searchview&query=FIELD%20Gradient%20CONTAINS%20gradienteasy.gif
```

This returns the results in an HTML table. What I would like to do is have the results formatted as JSON which I will then use client-side. Is this possible?

I know you can get JSON returned from a straight view by doing this:

```
http://site/activity.nsf/walking?readviewentries&outputformat=json
```

Answer (score 2):

Scott Good and I have done several sessions at a variety of conferences on generating and consuming JSON from traditional Domino applications (not using XPages). The most recent was the "JMP303 JSON in client- and server-side code Master Class" we gave at Lotusphere 2011. Link to the presentation materials and slides are: [here](http://www.scottgood.com/jsg/blog.nsf/BlogByMonth?OpenView&RestrictToCategory=02-2011)

/Newbs

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a view that is marked with the "Treat view contents as HTML" property and set up a column formula that generates the JSON syntax that you want'.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice post on OpenNTF with the code to create a very generic view which returns JSON for the documents that match the View's selection formula:
http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=use-transform-to-build-json-and-consume-the-output-in-an-xagent

That sample uses an "XAgent" (Xpage with no UI) to set the content-type header, etc. But you could probably do the same thing using a $$ViewTemplate form, if needed.